# Inspect the content of Time Machine single backup

Tags: time-machine, backup

Every time I make a backup with Time Machine, the size of the data backed up is always 2Gb+.
I don't understand where all these data are coming from.
Is there a way to inspect the content of the single backup?

Comment: Are you using torrent or usenet software?  If so, open the TM settings and add the working directories pointing to these to ignore.

Answer (score 3):

[TimeTracker](https://www.charlessoft.com/) - this allows you to see the individual files backed up to Time Machine.

(It's a little down on the website.)

Comment: I already tried this, but whenever I launch the app, it says it doesn't have the permission to read the backup file and becomes unresponsive.

Comment: @pasine I don't have that issue, it works fine for me. Are you logged in as an admin?

Comment: yes. maybe because the TM is on a NAS?

Comment: Same here and my TM is on a NAS too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the preinstalled `tmutil` utility on the command line (Terminal.app) to show the difference between two snapshots.

```
sudo bash

# Go to the time machine folder on your backup disk
cd /Volumes/BackupDisk/Backups.backupdb/mymac/

# List all available backups
ls -l

# Compare two backups
tmutil compare 2019-01-15-203957 2019-01-15-211038
```

Manpage entry for `tmutil compare`:

> If no arguments are provided, tmutil will compare the computer to the latest snapshot. If a snapshot path is provided as the sole argument, tmutil will compare the computer to the specified snapshot. If two path arguments are provided, tmutil will compare those two items to each other.  tmutil will attempt to inform you when you have asked it to do something that doesn't make sense or isn't supported.

Comment: Sounds good, but `cd: Permission denied: '/Volumes/whatever/Backups.backupdb` ... it seems that permissions arent allows allowing to do it like this.

Comment: @GhostCat Try as root (sudo bash), see updated answer.

Comment: I read your whole answer, I **am** in a bash that I started with sudo. I am root. But maybe I somehow messed up my backup disk. I can do backups to it, and time machine shows what is in, but I also cant change the password for it.

Comment: Looks like the folder structure has changed since then. I can't find a `mymac` directory, nor any directory containing backup files named from the date format.
However, there is a `com.apple.TimeMachine.SnapshotHistory.plist` file listing snapshots dates.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this question is pretty old now, but just in case anyone is still looking for something, I use [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/).